# extjs, getting null value instead of empty string on listeners

Tags: javascript, extjs

When the inputbox1 is empty, I'm getting a null value on listenners. What can I do to get a empty string "", instead of null value?

Thanks. The following is the code that I have. I think I can use the function to convert it, but I dont know where to put that function in the extjs code.

Thanks

```
var form = new Ext.FormPanel({
renderTo: 'SimpleForm',
title:'testing',
items:  [{
xtype:'fieldcontainer',
layout:'hbox',
combineErrors: true,
msgTarget: 'side',
defalts:{
        hideLabel:false,
        labelAligh: 'right'},
items:[{
    itemId: 'testing1',
    fieldLabel: 'Test1',
    name: 'test1',
    value:'',
    displayField:'name',
    xtype:'combo',
    valueField: 'name',
    store: 'input1store',
        listeners:{
            'change':{
                fn:function(combo,value){
                    Ext.getCmp('combo-testing2').clearValue();
                    input2store.setProxy({
                        type:'ajax',
                        url:'www.requesturl.com?format=json&source2'+combo.getValue(),
                        reader:{
                            type:'json',
                            root:'xml.result'
                        }
                    });
                    input2store.load();
                    }
                }
            }
        },{
            itemId: 'testing2',
            value:'',
            fieldLabel:'testing2',
            displayField: 'name',
            xtype:'combo',
            name:'testing2',
            valueField:'name',
            id:'combo-testing2',
            listeners:{
                onclick :{
                            single:true,
                            fn:function(){
                                input2store.load();
                            }
                }
            }
        }]
        }]
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just convert the value in place?

Using [`valueFrom`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-valueFrom) for example:

```
    url: 'www.requesturl.com?format=json&source2' + Ext.valueFrom(combo.getValue(), ''),
```

Comment: Great idea, but I just replace the Ext.valueFrom(null,''), for combo.getValue(), I no longer getting the value from inputbox1. I'm pretty new to this extjs, if possible, could you please show me where exactly that I need to make the change? Thanks you

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't intend to left that `null` in my example. I've updated the snippet in my answer. Is that how you replaced it?